# Error 404 on delete row codeigniter 2

Tags: codeigniter

im deleting a row in coneigniter2  but it takes me to 404 page 
(The page you requested was not found.)

this is my code

Controler Post

```
 class Posts extends CI_Controller{


public function index(){
 $data['title'] = 'Ultimos Post';
  $data['posts'] = $this->Post_model->get_posts();
   $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/index',$data);
     $this->load->view('templates/footer');
 }
   ...

   public function delete($id){
      //apagar post pelo id
         $this->Post_Model->delete_post($id);
          redirect('posts');

   }}
```

Post Model

```
 class Post_model extends Ci_Model{
  ...

    public function delete_post($id) {

              $this->db->where('id',$id);
                $this->db->delete('posts');

        }}
```

In the View.php

```
<?php echo form_open('/posts/delete/'.$post['id']);?>  
<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete">
```

Routes.php

```
$route['posts/create'] = 'posts/create';
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/view/$1'; 
$route['posts'] = 'posts/index'; 
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/view";
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Remove `$id` argument from controller function and use `$id = $this->uri->segment(3);`

Comment: i got same the same error it finds the id but goes like this [http://localhost/blog/posts/delete/2]

Comment: Please add your `routes` config to the question.

Comment: if you still getting error then you have to add url in route

Comment: added the route config to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Replace this code

**Controller**

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller{
...
    public function delete(){
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $this->Post_Model->delete_post($id);
        redirect('posts');
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Post_model extends Ci_Model{
...
    public function delete_post($id) {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('posts');
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<?php echo form_open('/posts/delete'); ?>  
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete">   
</form>
```

Comment: hows it possible check hidden input you can get id in hidden input?

Answer (score 0):

After deleting your redirecting its on Posts,
Which calling the index function of Posts controller .
The problem in you Posts controller index method , Please 
share that method or check it yourself .

Comment: i shared on the question

Answer (score 0):

Based on your config, `posts/delete/2` route to `posts/view/delete/2`. Change your `routes` config to following code:

```
$route['posts/create'] = 'posts/create';
$route['posts/delete/(:num)'] = 'posts/delete/$1';
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/view/$1'; 
$route['posts'] = 'posts/index'; 
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/view";
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing this on the controller and Route

Controller

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller{
 ...
  public function delete(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
       $this->Post_model->delete_post($id);
          redirect('posts');
    }
 }
```

Route.php

```
$route['posts/delete/(:num)'] = 'posts/delete/$1'
```